# html form on gmail sometime lose selected checkbox when submit

Tags: java

I'm using JavaMailSender to send a html form to my user. Html code for email look like this:

```
<form action="https://xxxxxx.com/handle-user-chose-answer" method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
  <label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
  <label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">
  <label for="vehicle3"> I have a boat</label><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

It's seem to work fine. Gmail display form as I expected.
here is an example email:
[image: 1]

But sometime (I don't know why and when) this form lose all selected stage of check box (all checked checkbox become uncheck ) when i press **Submit** button.

Please give me an idea. Thanks.

Comment: html is fine - what browser is displaying this e-mail, and have you looked at the browser console (F12) to see what it actually sends when the submit button is pressed? I really doubt that the problem has anything to do with sending it using Java